# Re-linking HTML files to CSS when folder structure changes

Tags: html, css, directory

Say I have a large number of HTML and CSS files, and I need to re-organize their folder structure. Are there any shortcuts (in VS Code preferably) to changing the links to stylesheets and hypertext links that  the HTML files contain?

Or would I have to do it all manually (restructure the folders and then manually copy each individual file path into it's respective point in each HTML file?)

Answer (score 1):

If the links to the files are within HTML or any other file, VS Code offers feature called "find and replace"
First one is what you want to change, second one is to what you want to change it to.

Search menu > Replace. And then you can either select "replace" or "replace all".

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics